# How to update json field's key name in rails using postgresql or activerecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a table named `cart` where `items` is in `json` type. The value in cart are as follows for 3 examples:

```
1. Cart(id: 1, name: 'Test', items: [{'desc'=>'First','names'=>'First'}, {'desc'=>'Second','names'=>'Second'}])
2. Cart(id: 2, name: 'Test', items: [{'desc'=>'First','names'=>'First'}, {'desc'=>'Second','names'=>'Second'}])
3. Cart(id: 3, name: 'Test', items: [{'desc'=>'First','name'=>'First'}, {'desc'=>'Second','name'=>'Second'}])
```

How can I update all the items key to have `name` key instead of `names` in rails? Such that it becomes as follow:

```
1. Cart(id: 1, name: 'Test', items: [{'desc'=>'First','name'=>'First'}, {'desc'=>'Second','name'=>'Second'}])
2. Cart(id: 2, name: 'Test', items: [{'desc'=>'First','name'=>'First'}, {'desc'=>'Second','name'=>'Second'}])
3. Cart(id: 3, name: 'Test', items: [{'desc'=>'First','name'=>'First'}, {'desc'=>'Second','name'=>'Second'}])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute <<-SQL
  UPDATE cart t1
  SET items = (
    SELECT json_agg(
      el :: jsonb - 'names' || jsonb_build_object('name', el -> 'names')
    ) FROM cart t2, jsonb_array_elements(t2.items) as el
    WHERE t1.id = t2.id
  )
SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

First get all records:

`all_carts = Cart.all`

> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Cart id: 2, name: "name1", items: "[{"desc":"First","names":"First"},{"desc":"Second"...",

then cycle each record and change the json key:

```
all_carts.each do |cart|
  jitems = JSON.parse(cart.items) # ---> [{"desc"=>"First", "names"=>"First"}, {"desc"=>"Second", "names"=>"Second"}] 
  jitems.each { |it| it['name'] = it['names']; it.delete('names') } # ---> [{"desc"=>"First", "name"=>"First"}, {"desc"=>"Second", "name"=>"Second"}] 
  cart.items = jitems.to_json # ---> "[{\"desc\":\"First\",\"name\":\"First\"},{\"desc\":\"Second\",\"name\":\"Second\"}]"
  cart.save
end
```